# Why the nested loop is not working well in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to create the table in html. But, I have a problem with the numbering.

The output that I got is:

[image: output]

What I want for my output is:

[image: desired output]

My code:event.html

```
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Event</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for i in event %}
    <tr> 
        {% for j in range(1, len) %} 
        <td>{{j}}</td> 
        <td>{{i.name}}</td> 

    </tr>
        {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: `for j, i in enumerate(event, 1):`

Comment: enumerate does not workout of the box in Jinja2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are doing a loop within a loop. You can add `zip` to you app.

```py
#...
app = Flask(__name__)
# ...
app.jinja_env.filters['zip'] = zip
```

```html
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Event</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for e, j in event | zip(range(1, len(event))) %}
    <tr> 
        <td>{{j}}</td> 
        <td>{{e.name}}</td> 
    </tr>

  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Sorry for asking, but when I tried to use enumerate or zip, it said that it is undefined. while, for j, e in zip(range(1, len(event), event). It said int' object is not callable. What's the problem?

Comment: I think you have overide `len` python function by using it as a variable. Python keywords are not supposed to be used as variable name. Change the place you did something like `len = ...` to something like `event_length`

Comment: Is it in app.py? This is my code:       return render_template('event.html', len=len(event),event=event)

Comment: Just pass `event=event`: In future don’t overide Python keywords ;)